# Pass attribute value into ng-repeat in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I set up a directive called ogPostList in the following way:

```
angular.module('myApp')
   .directive('ogPostList', function() {
   return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        page: '@'
      },
      templateUrl: '../scripts/directives/postList.html'
    };
 });
```

TemplateUrl:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchText" placeholder="Search" class="postListSearch" />
<table id="post_list_table" ng-controller="PostListController">        
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="postItem in {{page}} | orderBy:'toString()' | orderBy:'date':true | filter:searchText">
          <td><img title="{{'Post source ' + postItem.source}}" src="{{'images/' + postItem.source + '.svg'}}" height="20"/></td>
          <td>{{postItem.post}}</td>
          <td width="70">{{postItem.date}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The controller is set up as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('PostListController', function($scope, $http) {

        var postsList = [];
        var postsListSummary = [];
        var postsListMain = [];

        $http.get('dummy_content.json')
          .then(function(res){
          postsList = res.data;

          for (var iSummary = 0; iSummary < 10;iSummary++) {
              postsListSummary[iSummary] = postsList[iSummary];
           }

          for (var iMain = 0; iMain < postsList.length;iMain++) {
             postsListMain[iMain] = postsList[iMain];
          }

       });

       $scope.postsSummary = postsListSummary;
       $scope.postsMain = postsListMain;

     });
```

What I want to be able to do is when I declare a og-post-list element is to pass a value through my page attribute.

```
<og-post-list page="postsSummary"></og-post-list>
```

This value {{page}} should then go to the ng-repeat section in my templateURL and then pull the appropriate array as shown in my controller in order to populate my table

```
<tr ng-repeat="postItem in {{page}} | orderBy:'toString()' | orderBy:'date':true | filter:searchText">
```

However I see this is not allowed? Why is this and what would be a better way to tell my directive to display one of two arrays. The only difference between the 2 arrays is that 1 array one only contains 10 items and array 2 contains all elements pulled from my json file

Comment: Just tried your solution and it works beautifully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the compile function to modify the template before the compile function of `ng-repeat` is executed.

For example:

```
app.directive('ogPostList', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'postList.html',
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs) {

      tElement.html(tElement.html().replace('{{page}}', tAttrs.page));

      return {
        pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {},
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {}
      };
    },
  };
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/whwwHTZfMvlABlfkhjKK?p=preview

An alternative solution is to have a third variable, for example `postsDisplay` and use that in the `ng-repeat`. You can then set `postsDisplay` to either `postsSummary` or `postsMain` and switch between them.